# SF's migration text does not reflect our current topic matter

Tags: feature-request

Currently, when we migrate a question to another site, this is the text footer that gets attached to the question:

> **migrated** from [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/posts/677427/revisions) 13 mins ago
>
> This question came from our site for system and network administrators.

This statement does not accurately summarize what is on topic for SF, primarily because it does not limit the scope of what types of systems are being managed.

This footer is one of the very first ways that users of other SE sites are introduced to our existence, so it should probably be changed. Most people reading this would think that anything related to system administration should be steered our way.

Something like the following might work better:

> This question came from our site for managing systems and networks in a business environment.

We know that there's no way to force new users to read about our topic matter before posting a question, but it does help to control the innocent misunderstandings that are perpetuated among other SE sites. Fixing little messages like this will probably help us more in the long term than any amount of documentation changes on our site.

I put all of ten seconds into that rewrite, so if you've got something better, by all means present it.

Comment: It should currently be "managing information technology systems in a business environment".

Comment: @Michael It's not, at least looking at [some](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191852/how-to-get-the-adaptec-1200a-to-work-under-linux-at-udma-100-instead-of-66) [migrations](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191857/repairing-a-raid5-array) that occurred today. Are these migration messages defined globally, or on the destination sites?

Comment: The strings are specifically defined per-site as part of each site's metadata. Something is out of sync somewhere.